# fill up a bar with incremental value and timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I'm trying to do a loading bar with fixed timeout, says within 5 seconds, the bar should all filled up. I'm able to write the html and css but stuck in the js logic.

```
function App() {
  const [tick, setTick] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setTick(tick => tick + 10); //some calculation is missing
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(id);
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          background: "yellow",
          border: "1px solid"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            height: "10px",
            background: "black",
            width: tick + "%"
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-architecture-fuwcw

Comment: make tick+20 instead of tick+10

Comment: In the useEffect try to use setTick(tick + 20)

Comment: @VahidAkhtar where does the 20 come from? guessing?

Comment: 20 x 5 = 100, 10 x 5 = 50. if you use 10 you will get up to 50 since your setInterval runs each 1000 ms and is cleared at 5000.

Comment: @Jennifer you are running for 5 second and if you increment by 20 after 5times it will become 100 and that will be you 100% with to cover in you div

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a little.

I created 3 constants:

- maxLoad: Is the percentage to cover, in your case a 100%.
- fulfillInterval: It's the interval to fill a step in the bar.
- step: It's the calculation of the width to fill in the present iteration.

Then I changed a while the code adding 1 milisecond to the clearTimeout to ensure that it's going to work and... it's working. :)

Hope this helps.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [tick, setTick] = useState(0);

  const maxLoad = 100; // total percentage to cover
  const fulfillInterval = 5000; // clear interval timeout
  const step = maxLoad/(fulfillInterval/1000); // % filled every step

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setTick(tick => tick + step); // No dependency anymore
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(id);
    }, fulfillInterval+1);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          background: "yellow",
          border: "1px solid"
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            height: "10px",
            background: "black",
            width: tick + "%"
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: try with 6000 instead of 5000, the algorithm is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      if(tick !==100)
      setTick(tick => tick + 10); // No dependency anymore
    }, 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(id);
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [tick])
```

Replace your useEffect function like this.